# Get number of downloads for an iOS App through Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

Is there a way to get the number of users that downloaded an iOS App, without using the (developer.apple.com), only using Firebase analytics ??

P.S. I Registered the app on Firebase, and I can check all analytics, it's just that I can't find anything related to the number of downloads.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the list of key metrics: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317517?hl=en&ref_topic=6317489

Answer (score 1):

The only possibilities are:

- Active users
- Users active in last 30 minutes
- Top conversion events
- Engagement per user
- Total revenue
- Crash-free users
- App-version adoption
- Acquisition
- Retention cohorts
- Audience

[Ref...](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317517?hl=en&ref_topic=6317489)